# Manually inserting page breaks using abcPDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf

What's the easiest way to do this? I've done some research and came up with the

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

to put in the CSS but I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using it to generate PDF's and I'm looking for a way to start a new page without filling up empty space on a previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your concern fully, but creating a page break like that is the way to go.

Let's say you have some markup like:

```
<div>Some content here that doesn't fill the page</div>
<div style="page-break-before:always">Content here starts on a new page</div>
```

Then this will cause the second div to appear on a new page. Whether the previous page gets filled or not is upto the contents of the first div (or previous markup until that point).

The only requirement is that second `div` should not be *empty* or *hidden* (this is why you at least need *one whitespace character* inside the `div`). But if you have other content (and the content is `visible`), you don't have to worry about that either.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: My issue is that I'm not entirely sure how CSS works and the PDF is being generated using C# code. ABCPDF has an AddHTML method that will let styles and fonts be used on the PDF but using that to get the page break to work doesn't seem to be effective.

Comment: IF you can post some code or how your content looks, that would be helpful. Otherwise, have you considered `AddPage()` method to create a new page?